# Wordpress, make a page link automatically after a few seconds

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I am currently building a landing page in wordpress. This is a landingpage for a magento website. What i want to do is whenever i open a page through the menu, it should show the contents of that page for a few seconds. then it automatically links to the apropriate page on the magento webshop.

Can anyone tell me if there is a plugin for this or how i can pull this off without a plugin?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to achieve this is via javascript, and even then it's unreliable - nullified as soon as you find a user that has JS disabled. This should get you what you need though: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    self.location = "/magento/home.php";
}, 5000);
```

would redirect a user to your new page after 5 seconds - just drop it in the wordpress template page of choice.

(It's also my duty to inform you that this kind of behavior is horrendous usability, and may not get the reaction you're expecting from your audience. `</lecture>`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was expecting this, and i will do this a different way then.